# How to fetch a particular word from a txt file using grep in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a `txt` file. In that file, I want to filter a particular word.

Example:

```
$PILOT_FIRSTNAME $PILOT_LASTNAME. This is the final confirmation for this flight.
```

I want output like:

```
PILOT_FIRSTNAME

PILOT_LASTNAME
```

What are all the words with `$`, that word only fetch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using grep's PCRE (perl-compatible regular expression) mode:

```
$ grep -Po '\$\K\w*' yourfile
PILOT_FIRSTNAME
PILOT_LASTNAME
```

- `\$` : match literal `$`
- `\K` : (ignore it)
- `\w` : followed by zero or more word characters

---

If you want to *match and keep* the literal `$` character, then you don't need the `\K` modifier - and in fact you don't need PCRE at all, you can simply use

```
$ grep -o '\$\w*' yourfile
$PILOT_FIRSTNAME
$PILOT_LASTNAME
```

or (perhaps more portably)

```
grep -o '\$[_[:alnum:]]*' yourfile
$PILOT_FIRSTNAME
$PILOT_LASTNAME
```

Comment: If i  want with $ symobol($PILOT_FIRSTNAME) means.. Wat i do

Comment: @hikoo sorry I don't understand your question. Are you asking how to evaluate variables `$PILOT_FIRSTNAME` and `$PILOT_LASTNAME`? If so please edit your question to make it clear what you really want - preferably with a minimal, working example.

Comment: @steeldriver I think he wants the same regexp without the `\K`

Answer (score 5):

So if you want to print fields of the file as newline separated if starts with `$`, you can do:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^\$/){printf "%s\n",substr($i,2)}}}' file.txt
```

**Expanded form:**

```
awk '{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        { if($i~/^\$/)
                { printf "%s\n",substr($i,2) }
        }
     }' file.txt
```

Here we are iterating over the fields (`for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)`), if the field starts with `$` (`if($i~/^\$/)`), then printing it with a trailing newline starting from second character (`printf "%s\n",substr($i,2)`).

---

On the other hand, if the number of fields is fixed and not many, then `sed` is also a viable option, here assuming two fields:

```
sed -nr 's/^\$([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+\$([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1\n\2/p' file.txt
```

Matching `$` at the start of each whitespace separated field, capturing the field (`([^[:blank:]]+)`), then in the replacement set the fields as newline separated (`1\n\2`).

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
$PILOT_FIRSTNAME $PILOT_LASTNAME
$FOO $BAR
PILOT_FOO PILOT_BAR

$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^\$/){printf "%s\n",substr($i,2)}}}' file.txt
PILOT_FIRSTNAME
PILOT_LASTNAME
FOO
BAR

$ sed -nr 's/^\$([^[:blank:]]+)[[:blank:]]+\$([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1\n\2/p' file.txt
PILOT_FIRSTNAME
PILOT_LASTNAME
FOO
BAR
```